# How to trigger a ngrok get request in AWS API gateway and Lambda function?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to access some GET requests data from a personal ngrok webpage (that i created for testing purposes) by using the aws api gateway.

When i'm using the integration request i just can't get the data from the ngrok web page.

What i am trying to do is to catch some data from my ngrok page (by using the Api gateway) and then save them in dynamodb via a lambda function. I read the aws docs but i can find something that explains this process.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is, you can have one API GW method that uses a Lambda function as integration endpoint. The Lambda function could get the data from ngrok page and save it to Dynamo.

The other way is, you can have one API GW method with http integration pointing to your ngrok endpoint, and another API GW method with Lambda integration pointing to your Lambda function that puts the data into Dynamo. The caller should call the first method, and then call the second method with the output of the first method. So, the first option is a better one.

Comment: Thank you. The first option did the trick. I was misinterpreting the relation between api gateway and lambda. You helped me to finally understand this. Thanks again.